# Find base and dimension of given subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ $\in M_{4}(\mathbb R)$ and consider $S= \{M \in M_{4\times1}|T.M = 0\}$.
In the case $T=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1&-3\\0&1&0&-2\\-1&0&1&1\\-2&1&2&0\end{pmatrix}$, how can I find the base and the dimension of $S$?

Comment: How would you solve the matrix equation $Tx = 0$?

Comment: Let $X = \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}$. I'd check the conditions for $a, b, c, d$ so that the 4 equations derived out of that product equal zero. It's a linear system 4x4. Then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra**

Given $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, the four fundamental subspaces are
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{C}^{n} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
%
  \mathbf{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}
%
\end{align}
$$

---

---

**Resolve** $\mathbf{C}^{m}$: column space
$$
\mathbf{A} = \left[
\begin{array}{rcrr}
 1 & 1 & -1 & -3 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 -2 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Row reduction of $\mathbf{A}$. Form augmented matrix.
$$
\xi_{0} =
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
 \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}_{4} \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{rcrr|cccc}
 1 & 1 & -1 & -3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Reduction to row echelon form:

*column 1*

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\xi_{0}
%
=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccrc|cccc}
 \boxed{\color{gray}{1}} & 1 & -1 & -3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & 1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & 1 & 0 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & 3 & 0 & -6 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\xi_{1}
%
$$
The boxed entry identifies the pivot in a fundamental column.

*column 2*

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{crcc}
 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -3 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\xi_{1}
%
=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccrr|crcc}
 \boxed{\color{gray}{1}} & \color{gray}{0} & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \boxed{\color{gray}{1}} & 0 & -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{2} & \color{red}{-3} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\xi_{2}
%
$$
A span of the $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)}$ is given by the fundamental columns of $\mathbf{A}$, columns 1 and 2.
The red vectors form a span for $\color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$.

$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}
%
% range
&=
\text{span } \left\{ \,
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  0 \\
 -1 \\
 -2 \\
\end{array}
\right]}, \,
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right]},
\, \right\} 
% null
\oplus
\text{span } \left\{ \,
\color{red}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
\end{array}
\right], 
\,
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  2 \\
 -3 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right]}
\, \right\}%
\end{align}
$$

---

---

**Resolve** $\mathbf{C}^{n}$: row space
$$
\mathbf{A}^{T} = \left[
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 1 & 0 & -1 & -2 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
 -3 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Row reduction of $\mathbf{A}^{T}$. Form augmented matrix.
$$
\xi_{0} =
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
 \mathbf{A}^{T} & \mathbf{I}_{4} \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrr|cccc}
 1 & 0 & -1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -3 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Reduction to row echelon form:

*column 1*

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rccc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\xi_{0}
%
=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{crrr|rccc}
 \boxed{\color{gray}{1}} & 0 & -1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & 1 & 1 & 3 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & -2 & -2 & -6 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\xi_{1}
%
$$
The boxed entry identifies the pivot in a fundamental column.

*column 2*

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\xi_{1}
%
=
%
\left[
\begin{array}{ccrr|rccc}
 \boxed{\color{gray}{1}} & \color{gray}{0} & -1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \boxed{\color{gray}{1}} & 1 & 3 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{2} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\xi_{2}
%
$$
The red vector form a span for $\color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)}$.

$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbf{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)}
%
% range
&=
\text{span } \left\{ \,
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  1 \\
 -1 \\
 -3 \\
\end{array}
\right]}, \,
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  0 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
 -2 \\
\end{array}
\right]},
\, \right\} 
% null
\oplus
\text{span } \left\{ \,
\color{red}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
\end{array}
\right], 
\,
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  2 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right]}
\, \right\}%
\end{align}
$$

---

Another example is [Given a matrix and its reduced row echelon form, resolve the image and the kernel.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857727/given-a-matrix-and-its-reduced-row-echelon-form-resolve-the-image-and-the-kerne/2261304#2261304)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check how many vectors are Linearly independent and dim=number of that vectors.