# Given a matrix and its reduced row echelon form, resolve the image and the kernel.

Tags: linear-algebra

> The matrices $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-2&9&5&4\\1&-1&6&5&-3\\-2&0&-6&1&-2\\4&1&9&1&-9\end{bmatrix}$$
>   $$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&9&5&4\\0&1&-3&0&-7\\0&0&0&1&-2\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ are row equivalent. Find bases for Col $A$ and Nul $A$ and give the dimensions of these subspaces.

How exactly can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Let B be the 2nd matrix.  To find a basis for col(A), take the columns of A corresponding to the leading 1's in B.  To find a basis for nul(A), solve $Bx=0$ and find a basis for this solution space.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately: 
$$\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times 6}$$
The problem is to resolve a space of dimension $4$.

---

The row reduction identifies the *fundamental columns:*
$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{crrcr}
 \boxed{1} & -2 & 9 & 5 & 4 \\
 0 & \boxed{1} & -3 & 0 & -7 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \boxed{1} & -2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
The three fundamental columns identify the three vectors which span the $\color{blue}{range}$ space:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{rrrcr}
 \color{blue}{1}  & \color{blue}{-2} & 9 & \color{blue}{5} & 4 \\
 \color{blue}{1}  & \color{blue}{-1} & 6 & \color{blue}{5} & -3 \\
 \color{blue}{-2} & \color{blue}{0}  & -6 & \color{blue}{1} & -2 \\
 \color{blue}{4}  & \color{blue}{1}  & 9 & \color{blue}{1} & -9
\end{array} \right]
$$
Formally,
$$
 \color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)} = \text{span } \left\{ \,
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  1 \\
 -2 \\
  4 \\
\end{array}
\right]}, \,
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -2 \\
 -1 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right]}, \,
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 5 \\
 5 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]}
\, \right\} 
$$
The matrices have rank $\rho = 3$. 
Therefore, the range space $\color{blue}{\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)}$ has dimension $3$.

---

The *Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra* dictates that a matrix $\mathbb{A}\in\mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ induces the four fundamental subspaces:
$$
\begin{align}
%
  \mathbb{C}^{n} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red}{\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \\
%
  \mathbb{C}^{m} = 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}
%
\end{align}
$$

One vector is needed to complete the domain, the vector which will provide the span for $\color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)}$.

The $\color{red}{null}$ space vectors are found through Gauss-Jordan elimination of the augmented matrix.

Clear column 1.
$$
%
\left[
\begin{array}{rrcc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -4 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
  \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{I}_{4}
\end{array} \right]
%
=
\left[
\begin{array}{crrrr|rrcc}
 \color{gray}{1} & -2 & 9 & 5 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & 1 & -3 & 0 & -7 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & -2 & 6 & 11 & -8 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & 5 & -15 & -19 & 3 & 0 & -4 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
= \xi_{1}
$$

Clear column 2.
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{crcc}
 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -5 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\xi_{1}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccrrr|rrcc}
 \color{gray}{1} & \color{gray}{0} & 3 & 5 & -10 & -1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{1} & -3 & 0 & -7 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & 0 & 11 & -22 & -2 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & 0 & -19 & 38 & 5 & -9 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
= \xi_{2}
%
$$

Normalize row three, then clear column 3.
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccrc}
 1 & 0 & -5 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 19 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\xi_{2}
=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccrcr|rrrc}
 \color{gray}{1} & \color{gray}{0} & 3 & \color{gray}{0} & 0 & -\frac{1}{11} & \frac{2}{11} & -\frac{5}{11} & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{1} & -3 & \color{gray}{0} & -7 & -1\ & 1\ & 0\  & 0 \\
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & 0 & \color{gray}{1} & -2 & -\frac{2}{11} & \frac{4}{11} & \frac{1}{11} & 0 \\\hline
 \color{gray}{0} & \color{gray}{0} & 0 & \color{gray}{0} & 0 & \color{red}{\frac{17}{11}} & \color{red}{-\frac{23}{11}} & \color{red}{\frac{19}{11}} & \color{red}{1} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
$$
The red vector is 
$$
 \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} = \text{span } \left\{ \,
\color{red}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  17 \\
 -23 \\
  19 \\
  11 \\
\end{array}
\right]}
\, \right\}
$$

---

The decomposition of the image of $\mathbf{A}$
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{C}^{m} &= 
    \color{blue}{\mathcal{R} \left( \mathbf{A} \right)} \oplus
    \color{red} {\mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \right)} \\
%
% range
&=
\text{span } \left\{ \,
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  1 \\
 -2 \\
  4 \\
\end{array}
\right]}, \,
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -2 \\
 -1 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right]}, \,
\color{blue}{\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 5 \\
 5 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]}
\, \right\} 
% null
\oplus
\text{span } \left\{ \,
\color{red}{
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
  17 \\
 -23 \\
  19 \\
  11 \\
\end{array}
\right]}
\, \right\}
\end{align}
$$
The dimension of the $\color{red}{null}$ space is $1$.

---

The rank-nullity theorem as applied to this matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbf{R}^{4\times 6}_{3}$
$$
\begin{align}
  \text{rank } \mathbf{A} + \text{nullity } \mathbf{A} &= n \\
  3 + 1 & = 4
\end{align}
$$

---

Another example. Here the matrix is symmetric $m=n$ and it is more challenging to keep track of vector spaces: [Find base and dimension of given subspace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932435/find-base-and-dimension-of-given-subspace?rq=1)